# Why filtering an unsorted list is faster than filtering a sorted list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I've been playing with Java 8 `Streams - API` and I decided to microbenchmark `stream()` and `parallelStream()` streams. As expected the `parallelStream()` was as twice as fast, but something else popped up - If I sort the data before passing them to the `filter` it takes 5-8 times more time to `filter->map->collect` the result, than passing an unsorted list.

### Unsorted

```
(Stream) Elapsed time [ns] : 53733996 (53 ms)
(ParallelStream) Elapsed time [ns] : 25901907 (25 ms)
```

### Sorted

```
(Stream) Elapsed time [ns] : 336976149 (336 ms)
(ParallelStream) Elapsed time [ns] : 204781387 (204 ms)
```

### Here is the code

```
package com.github.svetlinzarev.playground.javalang.lambda;

import static java.lang.Long.valueOf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.github.svetlinzarev.playground.util.time.Stopwatch;

public class MyFirstLambda {
    private static final int ELEMENTS = 1024 * 1024 * 16;

    private static List<Integer> getRandom(int nElements) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>(nElements);
        for (int i = 0; i < MyFirstLambda.ELEMENTS; i++) {
            data.add(random.nextInt(MyFirstLambda.ELEMENTS));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static void benchStream(List<Integer> data) {
        final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        final List<Long> smallLongs = data.stream()
                .filter(i -> i.intValue() < 16)
                .map(Long::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        stopwatch.log("Stream");
        System.out.println(smallLongs);
    }

    private static void benchParallelStream(List<Integer> data) {
        final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        final List<Long> smallLongs = data.parallelStream()
                .filter(i -> i.intValue() < 16)
                .map(Long::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        stopwatch.log("ParallelStream");
        System.out.println(smallLongs);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Integer> data = MyFirstLambda.getRandom(MyFirstLambda.ELEMENTS);
        // Collections.sort(data, (first, second) -> first.compareTo(second)); //<- Sort the data

        MyFirstLambda.benchStream(data);
        MyFirstLambda.benchParallelStream(data);

        MyFirstLambda.benchStream(data);
        MyFirstLambda.benchParallelStream(data);

        MyFirstLambda.benchStream(data);
        MyFirstLambda.benchParallelStream(data);

        MyFirstLambda.benchStream(data);
        MyFirstLambda.benchParallelStream(data);

        MyFirstLambda.benchStream(data);
        MyFirstLambda.benchParallelStream(data);
    }
}
```

### Update

Here is a better benchmark code

```
package com.github.svetlinzarev.playground.javalang.lambda;

import static java.lang.Long.valueOf;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.github.svetlinzarev.playground.util.time.Stopwatch;

public class MyFirstLambda {
    private static final int ELEMENTS = 1024 * 1024 * 10;
    private static final int SMALLER_THAN = 16;
    private static final int WARM_UP_ITERRATIONS = 1000;

    private static List<Integer> getRandom(int nElements) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>(nElements);
        for (int i = 0; i < MyFirstLambda.ELEMENTS; i++) {
            data.add(random.nextInt(MyFirstLambda.ELEMENTS));
        }
        return data;
    }

    private static List<Long> filterStream(List<Integer> data) {
        final List<Long> smallLongs = data.stream()
                .filter(i -> i.intValue() < MyFirstLambda.SMALLER_THAN)
                .map(Long::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return smallLongs;
    }

    private static List<Long> filterParallelStream(List<Integer> data) {
        final List<Long> smallLongs = data.parallelStream()
                .filter(i -> i.intValue() < MyFirstLambda.SMALLER_THAN)
                .map(Long::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return smallLongs;
    }

    private static long filterAndCount(List<Integer> data) {
        return data.stream()
                .filter(i -> i.intValue() < MyFirstLambda.SMALLER_THAN)
                .count();
    }

    private static long filterAndCountinParallel(List<Integer> data) {
        return data.parallelStream()
                .filter(i -> i.intValue() < MyFirstLambda.SMALLER_THAN)
                .count();
    }

    private static void warmUp(List<Integer> data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MyFirstLambda.WARM_UP_ITERRATIONS; i++) {
            MyFirstLambda.filterStream(data);
            MyFirstLambda.filterParallelStream(data);
            MyFirstLambda.filterAndCount(data);
            MyFirstLambda.filterAndCountinParallel(data);
        }
    }

    private static void benchmark(List<Integer> data, String message) throws InterruptedException {
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Give it enough time to complete the GC cycle

        final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        MyFirstLambda.filterStream(data);
        stopwatch.log("Stream: " + message);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Give it enough time to complete the GC cycle

        stopwatch.reset();
        MyFirstLambda.filterParallelStream(data);
        stopwatch.log("ParallelStream: " + message);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Give it enough time to complete the GC cycle

        stopwatch.reset();
        MyFirstLambda.filterAndCount(data);
        stopwatch.log("Count: " + message);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Give it enough time to complete the GC cycle

        stopwatch.reset();
        MyFirstLambda.filterAndCount(data);
        stopwatch.log("Count in parallel: " + message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final List<Integer> data = MyFirstLambda.getRandom(MyFirstLambda.ELEMENTS);

        MyFirstLambda.warmUp(data);
        MyFirstLambda.benchmark(data, "UNSORTED");

        Collections.sort(data, (first, second) -> first.compareTo(second));
        MyFirstLambda.benchmark(data, "SORTED");

        Collections.sort(data, (first, second) -> second.compareTo(first));
        MyFirstLambda.benchmark(data, "IN REVERSE ORDER");

    }
}
```

And again the results are similar:

```
   16:09:20.470 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Stream: UNSORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 66812263 (66 ms)
16:09:22.149 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (ParallelStream: UNSORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 39580682 (39 ms)
16:09:23.875 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Count: UNSORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 97852866 (97 ms)
16:09:25.537 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Count in parallel: UNSORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 94884189 (94 ms)
16:09:35.608 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Stream: SORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 361717676 (361 ms)
16:09:38.439 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (ParallelStream: SORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 150115808 (150 ms)
16:09:41.308 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Count: SORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 338335743 (338 ms)
16:09:44.209 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Count in parallel: SORTED) Elapsed time [ns] : 370968432 (370 ms)
16:09:50.693 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Stream: IN REVERSE ORDER) Elapsed time [ns] : 352036140 (352 ms)
16:09:53.323 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (ParallelStream: IN REVERSE ORDER) Elapsed time [ns] : 151044664 (151 ms)
16:09:56.159 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Count: IN REVERSE ORDER) Elapsed time [ns] : 359281197 (359 ms)
16:09:58.991 [main] INFO  c.g.s.playground.util.time.Stopwatch - (Count in parallel: IN REVERSE ORDER) Elapsed time [ns] : 353177542 (353 ms)
```

So, my question is why filtering an unsorted list is faster than filtering a sorted list ?

Comment: I assume you have iterated this benchmark for a significant number of times and calculated average and std. deviation for the figures you are giving. Otherwise your numbers are garbage. You know, a PC has a scheduler, so CPU time and wall (clock) time will almost never match.

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array?rq=1

Comment: @Stefano Sanfilippo - Yes I have. But I'm not interested in the exact numbers, but why sorting the data slows down the preocess

Comment: @Andrei Andrei - I'm familiar with this SO question and that's exactly why I ask - because it exhibits the `OPPOSITE` behavior

Comment: @SvetlinZarev - excuse me. My mistake

Comment: Can you experiment to see which part is actually slower. Try removing the map method and measuring the results on sorted. Then try removing the collect to list and changing it to .count or something. Then try removing the filter. This way we will know where exactly to look for the reason.

Comment: Can you also try to sort the array in reverse order and see if the results are still worse for the sorted version.

Comment: @Stilgar - Removing the `map()` and `collect()` calls did not change the result. After all they operate on very small quantity of data after the `filter()`.I'll try sorting in reversed order and I;ll post the results

Comment: There is no change after sorting in reversed order

Comment: Discover [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Comment: @Robert Harvey It's not a duplicate. If you have read my question and the "duplicate" one you would've seen that it exhibits `the opposite` behavior. Either way the question have been answered.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? This is about cache miss, while the other question is about branch prediction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> When you are using the unsorted list all tuples are accessed in
>   memory-order. They have been allocated consecutively in RAM. CPUs love
>   accessing memory sequentially because they can speculatively request
>   the next cache line so it will always be present when needed.
>
> When you are sorting the list you put it into random order because
>   your sort keys are randomly generated. This means that the memory
>   accesses to tuple members are unpredictable. The CPU cannot prefetch
>   memory and almost every access to a tuple is a cache miss.
>
> This is a nice example for a specific advantage of GC memory
>   management: data structures which have been allocated together and are
>   used together perform very nicely. They have great locality of
>   reference.
>
> The penalty from cache misses outweighs the saved branch prediction
>   penalty in this case.

This question's accepted answer, answers my question too:
[Why is processing a sorted array slower than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023988/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-slower-than-an-unsorted-array)

When I create the original `List` sorted - i.e. it's elements are sequentally in memory, there is no difference in the execution time and it is equal to the  `unsorted` version when the `List` is filled with random numbers.